# DataTable to Nested Class Object

Tags: c#, json, class, nested

I have this Model which I am trying to fill with data from DataTable so I can serialize the model to JSON. However, I can't seem to find the correct way to fill in the order line items into the OrderDetails Class which is listed by OrderDetailsList.

So far, this is what I have.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

**Code**

```
List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();

orders = (from DataRow order in DTOrders.Rows
          select new Order()
          {
               ClientPO = "123456",
               MerchantOrderID = "123456",
               OrderDetailsList = (from DataRow orderDetail in DTOrderItems.AsEnumerable()
               where orderDetail["Order Number"].ToString() == order["Order Number"].ToString()
               select new OrderItem()
               {
                    //ClientJobRefDetail etc...
               }).ToList()
          }).ToList();
```

**Model**

```
    public partial class OrderModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("Order")]
        public Order Order { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Order
    {
        [JsonProperty("ClientPO")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long ClientPo { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("MerchantOrderID")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long MerchantOrderId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("OrderDetailsList")]
        public OrderDetailsList OrderDetailsList { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class OrderDetailsList
    {
        [JsonProperty("OrderDetails")]
        public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class OrderDetail
    {
        [JsonProperty("ClientJobRefDetail")]
        public string ClientJobRefDetail { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Product")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long Product { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Qty")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long Qty { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ShipMethod")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long ShipMethod { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ShipTo")]
        public string ShipTo { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ShipToPerson")]
        public string ShipToPerson { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ShipToAddress1")]
        public string ShipToAddress1 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ShipToCity")]
        public string ShipToCity { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ShipToState")]
        public string ShipToState { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ShipToZip")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long ShipToZip { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ShipToPhone")]
        public string ShipToPhone { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ShipToEmail")]
        public string ShipToEmail { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ExternalArtURL")]
        public Uri ExternalArtUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

**Desired Output after class is serialized into JSON**

```
{
  "Order": {
    "ClientPO": "999999",
    "MerchantOrderID": "123456",
    "OrderDetailsList": {
      "OrderDetails": [
    {
      "ClientJobRefDetail": "LINE123456",
      "Product": "369",
      "Qty": "1",
      "ShipMethod": "60",
      "ShipTo": "John Doe",
      "ShipToPerson": "John Doe",
      "ShipToAddress1": "120 9th Ave",
      "ShipToCity": "Longmont",
      "ShipToState": "CO",
      "ShipToZip": "80501",
      "ShipToPhone": "5055555555",
      "ShipToEmail": "jdoe@example.com",
      "ExternalArtURL": "http://example.com/print_ready_image.jpg"
    },
    {
      "ClientJobRefDetail": "LINE78910",
      "Product": "521",
      "Qty": "2",
      "ShipMethod": "60",
      "ShipTo": "John Doe",
      "ShipToPerson": "John Doe",
      "ShipToAddress1": "120 9th Ave",
      "ShipToCity": "Longmont",
      "ShipToState": "CO",
      "ShipToZip": "80501",
      "ShipToPhone": "5055555555",
      "ShipToEmail": "jdoe@example.com",
      "ExternalArtURL": "http://example.com/print_ready_image.jpg"
    }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to create a new OrderDetailsList

```
orders = (from DataRow order in DTOrders.Rows
select new Order()
{
    ClientPo = 123456,
    MerchantOrderId = 123456,
    OrderDetailsList = new OrderDetailsList()
    {
        OrderDetails = (from DataRow orderDetail in DTOrderItems.AsEnumerable()
                        where orderDetail["Order Number"].ToString() == order["Order Number"].ToString()
                        select new OrderDetail()
                        {
                            //ClientJobRefDetail etc...
                        }).ToList()
    }
}).ToList();
```